# For which categories can the Cartesian closedness of a category be described as a family of covariant functors?

Tags: lambda-calculus, cartesian-closed-categories

The paper [Functorial Polymorphism](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(90)90151-7) describes how parametric polymorphism can be described as dinatural transformations. It involves second order lambda calculus but my question is restricted to simply typed lambda calculus. If I understand it correctly, each  pair of (first order) lambda types $t_1$ and $t_2$ with $n$ free type variables, each term $u : t_1 \to t_2$ and each Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ indicates two functors
$\operatorname{F}_{t_1}, \operatorname{F}_{t_2} \in (\mathbf{C}^{\operatorname{o}})^n \times \mathbf{C}^n \to \mathbf{C}$
and a family of arrows
$u = \{ u_{\boldsymbol{A}} : \operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{A} \to \operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ |\ \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{C}^n \}$,
such that any two vectors
$\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbf{C}^n$ (each with $n$ objects of $\mathbf{C}$, called *base objects*) and each vector of arrows $\boldsymbol{f} : \boldsymbol{A} \to \boldsymbol{B}$, gives a commuting hexagon in $\mathbf{C}$:

$$
\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{B}\ \boldsymbol{A} 
\stackrel{ \operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{f}\ \boldsymbol{A}}{\to} 
\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{A} 
\stackrel{u_{\boldsymbol{A}}}{\to}
\operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{A} 
\stackrel{ \operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{f}}{\to} 
\operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{B}
$$

$$
\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{B}\ \boldsymbol{A} 
\stackrel{ \operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{B}\ \boldsymbol{f}}{\to} 
\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{B}\ \boldsymbol{B} 
\stackrel{u_{\boldsymbol{B}}}{\to}
\operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{B}\ \boldsymbol{B} 
\stackrel{ \operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{f}\ \boldsymbol{B}}{\to} 
\operatorname{F}_{t_2}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{B},
$$

where $\boldsymbol{A}$ in a position where a vector of arrows is expected indicates a vector of identity arrows for all the projections of $\boldsymbol{A}$, so $\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{f}\ \boldsymbol{A}$ “is” $\operatorname{F}_{t_1}\ \boldsymbol{f}\ (id_{A_1} \times id_{A_2} \times ... \times id_{A_n})$.

I will try to make some new definitions based on this and the $\star$ notation from the conference paper [Functional Pearl: F is for Functor](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/daniel.james/functor.html).

**Definition 1:** Given a simply typed lambda calculus type $t$ or term $u$ with $n$ type variables, a Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ and a vector of objects $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{C}^n$, the *interpretation* of $t$ at $\boldsymbol{A}$ is given by the infix operator $\star $ that takes lambda types and base type vectors to an object in $\mathbf{C}$

$$
t \star  \boldsymbol{A} = \operatorname{F_t}\ \boldsymbol{A}\ \boldsymbol{A} 
$$

and the interpretation of $u$ at $\boldsymbol{A}$ becomes an arrow in $\mathbf{C}$

$$
u \star \boldsymbol{A} = u_{\boldsymbol{A}}
$$

My **question** will be which family of categories
$\mathbf{STLC_1}, \mathbf{STLC_2}, \mathbf{STLC_3}, …$
has *just enough* structure to uniquely identify cartesian closed covariant functors

$$
\_ \star \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{STLC}_n \to \mathbf{C}
$$

for *all* Cartesian closed categories $\mathbf{C}$ and *all* vectors $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{C}^n$, that lift variables of atomic type $i$ to the $i$-th object in
$\boldsymbol{A}$.

Intuitively, one could think of the interpretation operator as a second order lambda calculus type abstraction of a lambda type or term where all $n$ type variables are bound in one single, fully uncurried type abstraction. When the result is applied to a vector $\boldsymbol{A}$, we get the desired object or morphism in $\mathbf{C}$.

**Example 1:** For $n = 1$, $\star$ is just type abstraction. For example, given one object $A \in \mathbf{C}$, it transforms the uniform Church numeral type like this:

$$
((a \to a) \to a \to a) \star A = 
\\
\Lambda T . ((a^T \to a^T) \to a^T \to a^T)\ A = 
\\
(A \to A) \to A \to A
$$

and the uniform Church numeral $2 = \lambda f . \lambda x . f\ f\ x$ like this:

$$
(\lambda f : a \to a . \lambda x : a . f\ f\ x : a \to a) \star A = 
\\
(\Lambda T . (f^{T \to T} . x^{T} . f\ f\ x))\ A = 
\\
\lambda f : A \to A . \lambda x : A . f\ f\ x : A \to A
$$

**Example 2:** With $n > 1$, $\star$ becomes something of a $n$ times uncurried type abstraction. If we see $\boldsymbol{A}$ as a product of $n$ objects $A_1 \times … \times A_i \times … \times A$, then $x^{\pi_i\ \boldsymbol{A}}$ means that $x$ has the type $A_i = \pi_i\ \boldsymbol{A}$, the $i$-th projection of $\boldsymbol{A}$. As an example, for any three base objects $A \times B \times C \in \mathbf{C}$, we get the composition type

$$
((b \to c) \to (a \to b) \to a \to c) \star (A \times B \times C)  = 
\\
(\Lambda T . (b^{\pi_2\ T} \to c^{\pi_3\ T}) \to (a^{\pi_1\ T} \to b^{\pi_2\ T}) \to a^{\pi_1\ T} \to c^{\pi_3\ T})\ (A \times B \times C) = 
\\
((B \to C) \to (A \to B) \to A \to C)
$$

with implementation

$$
(\lambda f : b \to c . \lambda g : a \to b . \lambda x : a . f(g\ x) \star (A \times B \times C) = 
\\
(\Lambda T . \lambda f^{(\pi_2\ T) \to (\pi_3\ T)} . \lambda g^{(\pi_1\ T) \to (\pi_2\ T)} . x^{\pi_1\ T} . f(g\ x))\ (A \times B \times C)  = 
\\
\lambda f : B \to C . \lambda g : A \to B . \lambda x : A . f(g\ x) : A \to C
$$

**Teaser:**
$$
\lambda n : (a \to a) \to a \to a . \lambda m : (a \to a) \to a \to a . (m \star (a \to a)) n : (a \to a) \to a \to a
$$

**Assumption 1:** The operator $\star$ is *"weakly closed":*

$$
\forall u, v, \boldsymbol{A}\ \exists\ w : w \star \boldsymbol{A} = (u \star \boldsymbol{A}) \circ (v \star \boldsymbol{A})
$$

that is, for any two composable simply typed lambda calculus terms $u$ and $v$ with $n$ type variables, and any vector $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{C}^n$ of any Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$, there exists a simply typed lambda calculus term $w$ with $n$ type variables such that the interpretation of $w$ at $\boldsymbol{A}$ is the composition of the interpretations of $u$ and $v$ at $\boldsymbol{A}$.

In some Cartesian closed categories, $w$ is not unique. For example, I am pretty sure that $\beta$- equivalent terms are mapped to the same arrow $\mathbf{Set}$.

**Definition 2:** The $w$'s of assumption 1 forms a set that will be called "the $\boldsymbol{A}$-compositions of $u$ and $v$"

$$
u \circ_{\boldsymbol{A}} v = 
\{w | w \star \boldsymbol{A} = (u \star \boldsymbol{A}) \circ (v \star \boldsymbol{A})\}.
$$

**Assumption 2:** All pairs of lambda terms $u$ and $v$ have a unique universal composition

$$
\forall u, v \exists ! u \circ v : \forall \boldsymbol{A} u \circ v \in u \circ_{\boldsymbol{A}} v
$$

such that for all vectors $\boldsymbol{A}$, $u \circ v$ is a $\boldsymbol{A}$-composition of $u$ and $v$. Concretely, I mean that $u$ and $v$ always have a unique composition that "works" as composition for any vector $\boldsymbol{A}$.

**Assumption 3:** The universal composition is associative.

I *think* that the universal composition is just substitution.

**Definition 3:** For each non-negative, whole number $n$, let $\mathbf{STLC}_n$ be the category of all simply typed lambda types with at most $n$ type variables, and all simply typed lambda functions between them, and composition is the global composition of assumption 2. If $n=0$, this is just the single object discrete category. By assumption 2, composition is always well defined since the universal composition is assumed to be unique. Composition in $\mathbf{STLC}_n$ is associative by assumption 3.

**Theorem:** For each Cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ and each vector $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{C}^n$ of $n$ base object, if assumption 1, 2 and 3 holds, then

$$
\_ \star \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbf{STLC}_n \to \mathbf{C}
$$

is a functor.

**Proof:** $\_ \star \boldsymbol{A}$ preserves composition by assumption 2.

In the case of one type variable, you might want to think about $\_ \star \boldsymbol{A}$ as a "type continuation", that is, the type level concept corresponding to continuations of functional programming.

**Assumption 4:** $\_ \star \boldsymbol{A}$ is Cartesian closed.

**Questions:**

1. Does assumption 1 through 4 hold?
2. What are the categories $\mathbf{STLC}_n$ called?
3. Can the functors $\_ \star \boldsymbol{A}$ be defined in terms of universal morphisms, recursively over the structure of the input term?
4. Does type continuation imply anything?

Besides explicit answers to the above, the following are also appreciated

1. Answers extended to lambda calculus with sum types and bicartesian closed categories.
2. References will do just as well as explicit answers.
3. Corrections to my horrible second order logic and lambda calculus syntax.